# How to display images one after another on a single page

Tags: wpf

This is my code , please let me know the solution for it.

```
var images = (from pd in SvarkWindow.prodlist where pd.Product_name.StartsWith(imgname) select pd.Image).ToList();

BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
b.BeginInit();

//b.UriSource = new Uri(images.ElementAtOrDefault(0), UriKind.Relative);
                    b.UriSource = new Uri("http://portal.liftech.in/presc/" + images.ElementAtOrDefault(0));

b.EndInit();
// ... Get Image reference from sender.
Image img1 = Productimage0 as Image;
img1.Source = b;
```

Comment: You write this is a WPF question but the question looks weby. You did not write what you already tried. One after the other requires at least a for loop and there is no here. Try reading about for loops, sleep, and UI-threads and regular thread. These issue will help you solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in this way.
look at the code.

```
                    ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://portal.liftech.in/presc/" + images.ElementAtOrDefault(0)));
                    System.Windows.Controls.Image image1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                    image1.Source = imageSource;
                    Grid.SetColumn(image1, 0);//image1 is added to column 0                        
                    Grid.SetRow(image1, 0);//row 0

                    ProductGrid0.Children.Add(image1);
```